# Restore MeeGo Harmattan Qt application from Apps Screen on N9

Tags: c++, qt, meego-harmattan

I am trying to publish my first application for N9 on Ovi Store but I have failed the QA:

SUMMARY: The application cannot back to front via clicking application icon after suspending the application in background.
STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
1. Download and install the content.
2. Launch the application.
3. Suspend the application in background.
4. Click the application icon.
ACTUAL RESULT: There is no response when clicking the application icon.
EXPECTED RESULT: The application backs to front. Features and controls in the content file must function as specified.

My application is written in C++ with Qt, there is one QWidget.
In the main function I am calling

```
Widget w;
w.showFullScreen();
```

I also override eventFilter

```
bool Widget::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange && m_created) {
        if (isActiveWindow()) {
            resume();
        }
        else {
            pause();
        }
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

But when reproducing the bug, I do not get to eventFilter at all. What should I do to get back to my app, when I press the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use `applauncherd` to launch your app by calling `invoker`. You could also use its booster feature to improve the startup time of your app (by using `MDeclarativeCache`).

Here is the documentation on how to use invoker:
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/showdoc.php?pkn=applauncherd-user-documentation&wb=daily-docs&url=Li94bWwvZGFpbHktZG9jcy9hcHBsYXVuY2hlcmQtdXNlci1kb2N1bWVudGF0aW9u

And here's how to use `MDeclarativeCache`:
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/showdoc.php?pkn=applauncherd-mdeclarativecache-documentation&wb=daily-docs&url=Li94bWwvZGFpbHktZG9jcy9hcHBsYXVuY2hlcmQtbWRlY2xhcmF0aXZlY2FjaGUtZG9jdW1lbnRhdGlvbg%3D%3D

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I've found the solution. It's a bit weird, but it works:

```
bool Widget::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange)
    {
        if (isActiveWindow())
        {
            resume();
        }
        else
        {
            pause();
        }
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::SockAct) // pure magic
    {
        activateWindow();
        resume();
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

After pressing the icon on the home screen, filetr QEvent::SockAct and restore application.